# Is there a way to fire the action in a notification from notification service?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications

I am writing a notification service in Android and currently reading and dismissing all the notifications from this Notification service.

```
Bundle extras = mNotification.extras;

title = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
notificationLargeIcon = (Bitmap) extras
                        .getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON);
smallContents = extras
                        .getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

In order to reply to the notifications is there a way to fire the "Reply" action? I can access the notification actions but I am not sure how we can fire the actions from within the Notification service.

```
Notification.Action[] actions = mNotification.actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the notifications are push, you can reply when you receive them (onMessage). 
If it's your app who generates local notifications, it's even clearer that you should not generate them. Instead, you have to reply directly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow you. I'm talking about NotificationListenerService (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and I'm trying to receive all types of notifications (eg: Hangouts, Facebook, Whatsapp and viber etc.) and replying from my service without opening the application.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Can you access to field actionIntent inside one action?